# Spring RESTful service returning JSON from another service

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

I have been creating Spring RESTful services for a while and typically I am building my own services so I create domain objects and populate them and the framework takes care of the conversion to JSON.

I have a situation now where I simply need my service to act as a pass through to another system's service that is already RESTful and returns JSON.

URL https://:/service/serviceInfo
Method  GET
HTTP Content Type   Produces:    application/json

I simply want to wrap this call (I will apply some security checks on the service) and pass that JSON returned straight back to my service without mapping it back to Java objects, only to return as JSON to the client. Is there a simple way to do this, with minimal code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if this works for you?

```
@RequestMapping("/child")
public String testMethod(@RequestParam String param) {
    return new RestTemplate().exchange("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class).getBody();
}
```

You just replace the url for your own. I can also guide you to using the RestTemplate with POST or DELETE requests etc. if you need. Also adding parameters or headers if you need. I've used it extensively in some projects.